# Prove that $G_{\delta(a)} = \delta G_a \delta^{-1}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $S$ be a set, and let $G$ be a subgroup of $A(S)$, the group of permutations on the set $S$.  Let $\delta\in G$, let $a\in S$, and $G_a$ denote the stabilizer of a.  Prove that $$G_{\delta(a)} = \delta G_a \delta^{-1}$$

Comment: Since they are equal, I know I must show they are subsets of each other.  I think the notation is confusing me.

Answer (score 1):

As you suggested, we should show each is a subset of the other.

$G_{\delta(a)} \supset \delta G_a \delta^{-1}$: an element on the right-hand side is of the form $\delta g \delta^{-1}$ where $g\in G_a$, that is, $g(a)=a$. What happens when you apply $\delta g \delta^{-1}$ to $\delta(a)$?

> Since $\delta g \delta^{-1} (\delta(a)) = \delta g (a) = \delta(a)$, we see that $\delta g \delta^{-1}$ is a stabilizer of $\delta(a)$, so it is in $G_{\delta(a)}$.

$G_{\delta(a)} \subset \delta G_a \delta^{-1}$: let $h \in G_{\delta(a)}$, that is, $h(\delta(a))=\delta(a)$. Then what happens when you apply $\delta^{-1} h \delta$ to $a$?

> Similarly, $\delta^{-1} h \delta (a) = \delta^{-1} h(\delta(a)) = \delta^{-1} \delta(a) = a$, so $\delta^{-1} h \delta (a)$ is a stabilizer of $a$. Then $h = \delta (\delta^{-1} h \delta) \delta^{-1}$ belongs to $\delta G_a \delta^{-1}$.

Comment: I'm sorry. I feel dumb but I'm not seeing it yet.

Comment: I got the first one now.  Thank you.  Stuck how to get the second: $\delta^{-1}h\delta$ to $a$

Comment: Nevermind.  got it!

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $g$ stabilizes $a$, that is: $g(a) = a$. Let $b = \delta(a)$. Since $\delta$ is bijective, we have that $\delta^{-1}(b) = a$.

So, $\delta g\delta^{-1}(b) = \delta(g(\delta^{-1}(b))) = \delta(g(a)) = \delta(a) = b$.

Evidently, then, $\delta g\delta^{-1}$ stabilizes $b = \delta(a)$.

The reverse argument is similar.

Answer (score 0):

it is straightforward that $\forall g \in G$
$$
g \in G_{\delta(a)} \equiv (g\delta(a)=\delta(a)) \equiv (\delta^{-1}g\delta(a) =a)\equiv \delta^{-1}g\delta \in G_a
$$
using the index notation for an inner automorphism, this may be written:
$$
G_a = G_{\delta(a)}^{\delta^{-1}}
$$
applying the inner automorphism $\delta$ to both sides of the equation yields
$$
G_a^{\delta} = G_{\delta(a)}
$$
i.e.
$$
G_{\delta(a)}=\delta G_a \delta^{-1}
$$